# Debug javascript iframe caller in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iframe

I am working on a site, which loads 100 of javascripts. In one page, I have a "iframe" which loading a youtube video. I see the "title" tag of the iframe is reset by some javascript. By doing some test, I see that javascript, find and replacing the iframe attribute by the tag name "iframe".

Can anyone help me, how to find who is replacing this iframe attribute?

```
<iframe src="/en-us/media/oembed?url=https%3A//youtu.be/C5oQYNDZtpI&amp;max_width=500&amp;max_height=281&amp;hash=7G5DUR_fZxyPVcv3Js9TxsId_i6OkO8HjHIRYH650Jo" frameborder="5" allowtransparency="" width="500" height="281" class="media-oembed-content" title="iframe"></iframe>
```

Comment: How would we be able to find that out when you post no code that might change anything?

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/project/oembed_lazyload

Comment: I need to find out which javascript file is changing the iframe title attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Simply open Chrome-Developer tools, find the desired `iframe` in the DOM-Tree (or open it via context-menu `Inspect element`), right-click the element and select `Break on -> attribute modification`. After reloading the page, whenever an attribute of the DOM-node is changed, the developer tools will jump to the sources tab and show you the exact line in the causing javascript file.

In case the file is minified, you can click the `{}` icon in the bottom left in Sources-tab to formate the code for better readability.

Comment: :( not working. I set the it  title="some video", but when loading, i see always  title="iframe".

I set the break on -> Attributes, but its not breaking.